# PDO: IF statement in query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was wondering if it is possible to use something like a if statement in a PDO query.
My current query is:

```
public static function UpdateTable( $id, $name, $variable )
{
    self::query("
        UPDATE  table
        SET     name = :name,
        WHERE   id = :id
    ", array(
        ":name" => $name,
        ":id" => $id
    ));
}
```

Which is prepared and executed by this:

```
public static function query($q, $params)
{
    $stmt = self::$con->prepare( $q );
    $stmt->execute( $params );
}
```

All of this works fine, but I also got the var $variable.
And I want that database column to be updated if $variable is not empty.

I can make a if / else statement in the "UpdateTable" function, but that quite ugly in my opinion en I couldn't find anything else on Google how to do this. So I would like to learn how to ;)

Comment: IMO it's better to do the `if` in PHP. The less logic in SQL, the better.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I allready thought it was better to deal with this in PHP instead of in the SQL. But thought maybe there is something I still don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also tokenize your your queries based off any conditions in php like the following:

```
 public static function UpdateTable( $id, $name, $variable )
 { 
   $params = array(":name" => $name, ":id" => $id);
   $update = "";

   if(isset($variable)) {
     $update = ", columnname = :variable ";
     $params[':variable'] = $variable; 
   }

   $query = "UPDATE  table SET name = :name {$update} WHERE id = :id ";

   self::query($query,$params);
 }
```

Comment: Wow, awesome thanks! Didn't know I could do it this way! I will look into this this must also work for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You really should do it in the PHP function - it would save a trip to the database in case `$variable` is empty. But, if someone points a gun to your head and threaten to pull the trigger unless you do it in the query, you can add it to the where clause:

```
UPDATE  table
SET     name = :name,
WHERE   id = :id
AND     :variable IS NOT NULL
```

or something like that(never worked with PHP, so I don't know if passing a null variable will turn into SQL null...)